# On common x-axis how to draw a chart with different unit of dataset array (multi line chart)

Tags: d3.js, charts, highcharts, angular-nvd3, vega-lite

[image]

As you can see in the above picture, I have two type of data array, In one set of data on y-axis I am getting in `degree celsius` and another of data array I am getting in `hertz (hz)`,

And the is quite possibly at runtime I can get some other dataset as well.

The major challenge is as :

1. There must a be the common x-axis
2. User can re-arranged these line using drag &drop
3. User can do zoom-in and zoom-out operation to see hidden y-axis values

I went through some of highcharts examples but its actually no solving my requirement,
any other charting library if anybody can suggest me

I will appreciate any suggestion

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts library you can use multiple Y axes on same X  axis.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Multiple Type of Dat'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        opposite: true

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }

    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Frequency',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} hertz',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 80,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 55,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Frequency',
        type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 2,
        data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' hertz'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' °C'
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

API Reference:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

You can use  `zoomType: 'xy'` also for allow user to zoom in and zoom out in chart.